# Tools option not available in Watson Data Platform

Tags: watson, watson-studio

I am unable to see the Tools option in the watson data platform as shown in the attachment. Can someone please help me how to enable it?

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: what is the version you are using

Comment: you must use same version as of software

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and I fixed it by

1. click your name initial at the top right corner
2. select "Add other apps"
3. add "Watson studio"

Hope this helps.